# removing space after first hline of tabular

Tags: tables, spacing

How can I either remove the space after the first hline of the right tabular (the second tabular in the following code) or if that is not possible, what kind of value do I have to pass to the trim-parameter of adjustbox (e.g. `{valign=T, trim=0 \parskip}` or something like that) in order to get rid of this space? Note that I don't care about the hline. It's just here to show you, what kind of space I want to remove.

Thank you!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\adjustbox{valign=T}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}\hline
\Huge X1\\\\
\tiny X2
\end{tabular}}
\adjustbox{valign=T}{\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}}\hline
X1\\\\X2
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround (you can remove the `\adjustbox`es):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\adjustbox{valign=T}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
\hline
\Huge X1\\\\
\tiny X2
\end{tabular}}%
\adjustbox{valign=T}{\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}}
\hline
\\[-3.31ex]X1\\\\X2
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The two `\adustbox` instructions don't do anything, or do they? AFAICT, all the work is done by the instruction `\\[-3.31ex]`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Mico Yes, as I said in the answer they can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Not a full solution, but some (hopefully helpful) comments about the lack of action of the `\adjustbox` instruction in the present case and some suggestions for a workaround.

In the example code you've provided, it's important to realize that the fact that the upper edge of the "Huge" X in the left-hand tabular happens to touch its `\hline` is *pure coincidence*; it is *not* caused by the presence of the `\adjustbox{valign=T}{...}` instruction. You can check this out for yourself by leaving off the `\adjustbox` instruction.

So, what to do to get the desired alignment of the upper edge of the (normal-sized) letter "X" with the horizontal line? I can't come up with an elegant solution, but only with two suggestions for a brute-force workaround: (a) the "TeX primitive commands" `\raise` and `\hbox` and (b) the command `\raisebox` that's provided by the `graphicx` package. By how much the material should be raised will depend, naturally, largely on the size of the material. For the case of "X1" in a document where the natural fontsize is `11pt`, `2pt` seems to be the correct amount.

Incidentally, shifting the first row of the `tabular` does not affect the baseline of the second row. If you need to displace vertically the entire `tabular` environment, you should encase it in a `\raise...\hbox{...}` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx} % provides \raisebox macro
\begin{document}
% 1st tabular
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
  \hline
   {\Huge X1}\\ X2
\end{tabular}
% 2nd tabular
\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}}
  \hline
  \raise2pt\hbox{X1}\\ X2 % \raise and \hbox are "primitive" commands
\end{tabular}
% 3rd tabular
\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}}
  \hline
  \raisebox{2pt}{X1}\\ X2
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```